# How to get Size of UIImage in Bytes in iOS 4.0+?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to pick an image from the photo library or from the camera.
The delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

Gives me the `UIImage` object. I need to find the size of the image in `bytes` for my application.

Is there any way I can get the file type of the image and also the size in the bytes?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((image), 1.0)];

int imageSize = imageData.length;
NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %i ", imageSize);
```

Comment: what should be the right value passed for compression quality in UIImageJPEGRepresentation? i see 0.5 here, that makes my calculated size smaller than original & 1 makes it bigger.

Comment: it is very important to know which compression rate was used while compressing the image from library. I was informed, that the default compression rate for iOS 8 camera is 92%, but this doesn't mean that all images in your library have this compression ratio, some of them may be captured from another camera or OS.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old question but creating a `NSData` object just to get the byte-size of an image can be a really expensive operation. Image can have over 20Mb and creating equally sized object just to get the size of the first one...

I tend to use this category:

**UIImage+CalculatedSize.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (CalculatedSize)

-(NSUInteger)calculatedSize;

@end
```

**UIImage+CalculatedSize.m**

```
#import "UIImage+CalculatedSize.h"

@implementation UIImage (CalculatedSize)

-(NSUInteger)calculatedSize
{    
    return CGImageGetHeight(self.CGImage) * CGImageGetBytesPerRow(self.CGImage);
}

@end
```

You simply import the `UIImage+CalculatedSize.h` and use it like this:

```
NSLog (@"myImage size is: %u",myImage.calculatedSize);
```

Or, if you want to avoid using categories:

```
NSUInteger imgSize  = CGImageGetHeight(anImage.CGImage) * CGImageGetBytesPerRow(anImage.CGImage);
```

**EDIT:**

This calculation of course has nothing to do with JPEG/PNG compression. It relates to underlaying [CGimage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/):

> A bitmap (or sampled) image is a rectangular array of pixels, with
>   each pixel representing a single sample or data point in a source
>   image.

In a way a size retrieved this way gives you a worst-case scenario information without actually creating an expensive additional object.

Comment: +1. On top of that, the call to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` itself is both memory and cpu hungry.

Comment: But would this even return correct image size? JPEG and PNG are both compressed.

Comment: This does not return correct size, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1296933/1418457

Answer (score 2):

From:[@fbrereto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153535/fbrereto)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1296933/2789144):

The underlying data of a `UIImage` can vary, so for the same "image" one can have varying sizes of data. One thing you can do is use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to get the equivalent `NSData` constructs for either, then check the size of that.

From:[@Meet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942110/meet)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076993/2789144):

```
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
 NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0); 
 NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo{
   UIImage *image=[editInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   NSURL *imageURL=[editInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
   __block long long realSize;

   ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock=^(ALAsset *asset)
   {
      ALAssetRepresentation *representation=[asset defaultRepresentation];
      realSize=[representation size];
   };

   ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock=^(NSError *error)
   {
      NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
   };

   if(imageURL)
   {
      ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary=[[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
      [assetsLibrary assetForURL:imageURL resultBlock:resultBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
   }
}
```