# How to get UIImage correct file size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, filesize

When I take the picture on camera, I'd like to get file size of UIImage.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {
     UIImage *originalimage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     NSData *dataForPNGFile =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(originalimage);
     int fileLengthPNG = dataForPNGFile.length;
     NSLog(@"-->> fileSizePNG : [%i]", fileLengthPNG);
}
```

I wrote this code but the system console returned "fileSizePNG : [10550292]".
I think 10550292 bytes is too big.

It is about 10MB so I thought my code is mistake.

If you find any problems, could you please let to me?

Comment: did you saved the file and checked the file size?

Comment: You convert the image to a PNG to check the file size which will be probably be larger than the original JPEG in the camera roll. You will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7500214/418715

Comment: Thank you everyone!

I used ALAssetsLibrary after saving image.
This is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd `[dataForPNGFile writeToFile:@"test.png" atomically:YES]`

and then go to the actual file and look at the size of the file. Then you'll know for sure.

Comment: The same amount of data will be written to the file, so whats the point of this?