# thumbnailImageAtTime , size of generated thumbnail?

Tags: ios, objective-c

using :

```
UIImage  *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

what is the size of the generated thumbnail ?

Comment: UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: yourUIImage];
    
    CGFloat height = imageView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat width = imageView.frame.size.width;  
is it helpful to u.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the bytes:

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 0); 
NSLog(@"Size of Thumbnail in bytes:%d",[imgData length]);
```

Answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076993/2889834

Comment: thanks, I am only interested in width/height , sorry I should have stated it in my question....

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check:

```
thumbnail.size.height;
thumbnail.size.width;
```

That method is deprecated, by the way, you shouldn't be using it anymore:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Comment: yes, I read the link... that's why I asked it, it wa sky first intent