# iOS - Get File Size of Image Selected From Photo Reel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building an app that allows users to select photos and videos from their device and upload them to the server. Trying to get the file size (in bytes) of each item select, can anyone help me out?

```
if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypePhoto){ // image file
        if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]){
            NSURL* urlPath=[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

            item = [BundleItem itemWithPath:urlPath AndDescription:nil];
            item.itemImage = [dict objectForKeyedSubscript:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            item.itemType = 1; // image
            item.itemSize = // what do I need here??
            [m_items addObject:item];
        }
    } else if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypeVideo){ // video file
        if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]){
            NSURL* urlPath=[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
            item = [BundleItem itemWithPath:urlPath AndDescription:nil];
            item.itemImage = [dict objectForKeyedSubscript:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            item.itemType = 2; // video
            item.itemSize = // what do I need here??
            [m_items addObject:item];
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Getting NSCocaoErrorDomain 256 with videos:

```
            NSURL* urlPath=[dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

            item = [BundleItem itemWithPath:urlPath AndDescription:nil];
            item.itemImage = [dict objectForKeyedSubscript:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            item.itemType = 2; // video

            //Error Container
            NSError *attributesError;
            NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[urlPath path] error:&attributesError];
            NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
            long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longValue];
            item.itemSize = fileSize;

            [m_items addObject:item];
```

Comment: file size in MB or image pixel?

Comment: check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296707/get-size-of-a-uiimage-bytes-length-not-height-and-width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For only **image** data selection:

```
item.itemImage = (UIImage*)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(item.itemImage, 1); //1 it represents the quality of the image.
NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);
```

Hope this will help you.

Below method is generalize, it will work for both image and video:

Something like this should take care finding the file size of a selected image or video returned from the **UIImagePickerController**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

        NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        //Error Container
        NSError *attributesError;
        NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[videoUrl path] error:&attributesError];
        NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
        long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
}
```

Comment: what if the file selected is a video?

Comment: @AdamTheRaysFan Updated my ans with secondary option which will work for both.

Comment: can you see my edit above? I'm getting a domain error when trying to get video size

Comment: First try the code I posted, in your question edit, you have used UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage, check line --- item.itemImage = [dict objectForKeyedSubscript:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];