# How can I get the size of the video that is taken from UIimagePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

I am using below code but it is not showing accurate size,Suppose my file size is 50Mb,But it is showing around 90MB.

```
NSError *error;
NSURL * mediaURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSDictionary * properties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:mediaURL.path error:&error];
NSNumber * size = [properties objectForKey: NSFileSize];
```

and also i tried below code

```
NSDictionary *attribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:moviePath error:&error];
if (attribs) {
    NSString *string = [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:[attribs fileSize] countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

It is also same result.I want exact file size.Can any body help me.
Thank you

Comment: Have you referred this answer on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27245011/6742121? @Bittoo

Comment: actually i am getting this result after compressing video. but after compression video size is increasing is there any reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSError *attributesError;
NSURL *videoUrl=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[videoUrl path] error:&attributesError];
    NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
    NSLog(@"SIZE OF VIDEO: %0.2f Mb", (float)fileSize/1024/1024);
```

This code is completely work

Comment: already i tried that but no use.did you get exact size of video using this code ?

Comment: Thanks for the replay but are you checked for large file like more than 100MB?