# How to get image size in KB or Mb from image picker?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I'm facing some issue to get image size in my code here is what I'm doing:

```
let imageData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(images[0], 1) as! NSData 
let formatter = ByteCountFormatter() 
formatter.allowedUnits = .useKB 
formatter.countStyle = .binary 
let imageSize = formatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(imageData.length))
print(imageSize)
```

Comment: NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imgBackground.image, 1);
                int imageSize   = imageData.length/1024.0; try this

Comment: What do you mean by image picker? Can you please give more detail?

Comment: Im using UIPickerView to select image from my gallery and im setting it particular view , but there are memory contraints on it

Comment: You shouldn't create an array of images. You should create an array with their URLs. No wonder you are having some memory issues

Comment: @Ravipanchal i have tried it, Im crossChecking size which im getting on my log with the actual size on my phone but its not matching

Comment: `let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!; print(ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(data.count), countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.file))`

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49878038/1140335)

Comment: .binary will do over there

Comment: @LeoDabus I agree but Apple mentioned [this in doc](https://i.imgur.com/iMtNHNF.png) so I used `.file`.

Comment: @LeoDabus `.memory` is use for `binaryStyle` and `.file` is for `decimalStyle`. Shouldn't we need to show the size in decimals like `1.7 MB`?

Comment: if you are passing the Data count you should use `.memory` if you are passing the fileSize you should use `.file`

Comment: to use .file it would be something like this `if let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL {
            do {
                if let fileSize = (try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey])).fileSize {
                    print("fileSize", fileSize)
                    let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
                    formatter.allowedUnits = .useKB
                    formatter.countStyle = .file
                    let imageSizeInKB = formatter.string(for: fileSize) ?? ""
                    print("imageSizeInKB:",imageSizeInKB)
   } } catch { print(error)}}`

Comment: But when I test it with `.file` it prints `1.7 MB` and `.memory` also prints `1.7 MB`. I will change it to `.memory` but in which case it will give different result?

Comment: @TheTiger I don't know exactly in which circumstances it would make a difference. Note that you can also get `.totalFileSizeKey`, `.fileAllocatedSizeKey` and `.totalFileAllocatedSizeKey` which includes the metadata file size

Comment: @LeoDabus Okay, Thanks for your comments. I change it to `.memory`.

Answer (score 1):

Here You can get image size

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
            var Size = Float()
            var data = Data()
            btnCancel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            if let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String {

                if mediaType  == "public.image" {
                    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 1.0)!
                      //Here you get MB size
                        Size = Float(Double(data.count)/1024/1024)

                      //For Kb just remove single 1024 from size 

                      // I am checking 5 MB size here you check as you want
                        if Size <= 5.00{
                            // Here your image
                        }  
                    }
                }
                else
                if mediaType == "public.movie" {
                    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
                    data = try! Data.init(contentsOf: videoURL!)
                    Size = Float(Double(data.count)/1024/1024)
                    if Size <= 5.00{
                        //your video here
                    }
                }
            }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
                if Size > 5.0{
                    Utilities.showAlertView(title: "title", message: "message")
                }
            }
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: You should just get the image URL and check the file size

Comment: why `if Size <= 5.00`?

Comment: It's just example

Comment: This is not the real size of the image. The image might not even be a jpeg anymore

Comment: but you can get actual size in Size parameter, so you can check within your limit. I have alreay tested this code and running in my app too.

Comment: Again you should just get `UIImagePickerControllerImageURL` and use `URL` `resourceValues` method to get the file size `url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey]).fileSize`

Comment: Why would you load the whole movie to memory just to check its size? This is insane

Comment: Yes, that's issue like when there is a big size of image then it will take load to convert into data so I will try your solution, Thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply check the size in KB by the following `UIImage` extension:**

```
extension UIImage {
    func logImageSizeInKB(scale: CGFloat) -> (Int, Data) {
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, scale)!
        let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = ByteCountFormatter.Units.useKB
        formatter.countStyle = ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.file
        let imageSize = formatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(data.count))
        print("ImageSize(KB): \(imageSize)")

        return (Int(Int64(data.count) / 1024), data)
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Can use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` too for png image size. By the way PNG images are heavier than JPEG/ JPG.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, to get image size when getting an image from picker view.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);

        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        //get the size of image
        let imgData: NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((chosenImage), 1)!)
        let imageSize: Int = imgData.length
        print("size of image in MB: %f ", Double(imageSize) / 1024.0/1024.0)
    }
```